# How to have a select with a dropdown grid in angularjs and bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was looking to see if its possible to have a select with a dropdown that is able to show a grid inside the dropdown container. after lots of googling, I still can't find an example that uses angularjs.

does some one know how to achieve this or point me to a opensource controls that I can use.

something like below:

[image]

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

A good JavaScript select library is Select2: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2. But that's not going to get you a grid like that.